# como ocultar/contraer una variable tipo diccionario en visual studio Code (python)

Tags: visual-studio

quería preguntar si alguien sabe como puedo ocultar o contraer una variable tipo diccionario como pasa con las funciones, es para optimizar la edición y no ver tanto código, ni tener que hacer scroll. Anteriormente podía contraerlas, pero de un momento para acá, ya no lo puedo hacer.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen que comparto de un código de muestra, puedo contraer la Clase "VerticalScro......" pero no puedo contraer la variable "diccionario", no se por qué de un momento para acá no me deja hacerlo, si antes si podía.

Si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando en varias partes encontre la respuesta, por si alguien la necesita.

Se debe ir a "File->Preferences->Settings" o usar la combinación de teclas "ctrl + ,"

aparece una ventana de configuración, allí, en el buscador se debe poner "folding" y configurar la opción "Folding strategy" en "identation"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma queda funcionando el contraer para las variables tipo Diccionario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]